# Logic to evenly distribute an array

Tags: distribution

I need help to create a program to distribute to n number of arrays.

Eg. I have an array,

```
array=(20,80,340,10,96,100,40,870,65)
```

Output expected is something like this, this is just an example,

```
array1=(870)
array2=(340)
array3=(100,20,10)
array4=(96,40)
array5=(80,65)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help. What rules do you use to get the five resulting arrays? Besides the code you posted is not valid perl.

Comment: I need a logic for this. The one i posted is not a perl code. I tried to explain in an eg.

Comment: I don't see any pattern...do you just want to assign elements to arrays at random? If not, could you please explain why each number goes in each array?

Comment: We can assign the numbers to any array. But end of assigning, it should be equally distributed. The given arrays are just an example. It can change. My aim is to distribute the time in seconds(say executstion time of a program) to different servers so that it will complete equally. So the first array @time_array is the history execution time of some programs. Now i want to distribute it to different servers to reduce total execution time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

my $servers_number = 5;
my @source = (20, 80, 340, 10, 90, 100, 40, 450, 60);
my @result;

@source = sort {$b <=> $a} @source;
my @server_times;

foreach my $time_chunk (@source)
{
    my $server_index = get_less_loaded_server_index();
    $result[$server_index] //= [ ];

    push @{$result[$server_index]}, $time_chunk;
    $server_times[$server_index] += $time_chunk;
}

sub get_less_loaded_server_index
{
    my $lessest_time;
    my $selected_server;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $servers_number; $i++)
    {
        $server_times[$i] //= 0;

        if (!defined $selected_server || $lessest_time > $server_times[$i])
        {
            $lessest_time = $server_times[$i];
            $selected_server = $i;
        }
    }
    return $selected_server;
}

say Dumper(\@result);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question right and you need to split array of numbers to n arrays keeping them even as possible, the first way i see:

1. Sort source array descending
2. Calculate perfect amount of seconds fits in sub-array (sum elements and div by n-1)
3. Start iterating source array from the beginning putting every element into first subarray until sum of its elements less than perfect amount.
4. If putting next element to subarray will exceed the perfect amount, start running from the end, and put some low numbers.
5. Create new subarray and continue running from the index you've stopped at the p 3.

Comment: Greedy algorithms are not always the best.

Comment: Thank. But, My aim is to distribute the time (history executstion time of a program ) to different servers so that it will complete equally next time. So the first array @time_array is the history execution time of some programs. Now i want to distribute it to different servers to reduce total execution time. When i take decending order and start put everything in first array, it means all bigger projectd(in term of time to execute) will be in first array. I want atleast all bigger projects distributed to different arrays. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @bipll it was not the best one, just first thought.

Comment: @Rameez not sure. If you are interested in even balancing, it doesn't matter if heavy tasks are distributed evenly. Don't see a problem if first server do one 100-seconds task and the second one do 100 one seconds. Suggested algorithm divides total time pool "evenly", not balancing tasks number.

Comment: @Alexandr I think that will not solve my problem. This logic I have tried but problem now all big programs executing in same server. I want to distribute to others and take some smaller one with big programs. I am not getting a logic for this. Thats why posted here

Comment: @Rameez may be you should change your question. Your is about splitting array. Suggested algorithm does it, but you need something else.

Comment: Its not about my question. Its about what logic what i want. It should solve my problem

Comment: @Rameez Would be nice to describe the logic you want. Logic described in your question handled by offered algorithm.

Comment: Edited the requirement. I need logic for this. Please let me know if any doubt.

Comment: @Rameez guess my second answer does what you want